# Proffesional Systems Design

Tags: c#

Please advise me and correct my understanding if I am in error. In my opinion, any programmer wanting to develop an accounting system should consider two approaches from the two mentioned below:

1. Make all clients connect to SQL server directly by changing the connection string in all clients to refer to SQL server.
2. Make all clients PCs contacting the server using stream, TCP or UDP ports ...etc, then the server makes a connection to the database then sends the result to its clients through streams and I/O methods. In other words all clients do not contact the SQL server themselves in a direct manner. Instead they just contact the server PC (this may have the database or not).

Are the above ideas correct and which one is common?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146917/server-client-programming-in-accounting-systems

Comment: they inform the post will be closed

Comment: Correct in what sense? You offer two situations, to connect directly to the database or not to. This is a binary option, **if** your software is based around a single, central database then you must choose one but there should be many more factors that go into that decision. It is unclear what you are actually asking for or what you expect from an answer.

Comment: I am starting to see a pattern. Someone not familiar with some technology clearly is asking for an explanation and instead of reaching out to him some folks vote him down on irrelevant formalities. Often the same lot too... Please ask yourselves, am I really doing this to improve the site or do I have have some personal issues and am I just damaging the image of the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches are reasonably common.    They even have names:

1. This is a client-server architecture.  Sometimes called "thick client" because the application's business logic is in the client.
2. This is a three-tier or application-server architecture.  The business logic is in the application server.

If I were designing it myself, I would use an application server architecture for an accounting system, since presumably there is a need for audit trails and perhaps a reasonably sophisticated authorization system (i.e. to pay an invoice having value over $X, approval from person Y is needed, ensuring that only invoices having purchase order numbers should be paid unless they're under $100 and from approved vendors, etc.)

Edit: the other benefit of a three-tier architecture is that you can more easily change the data storage layer (to change database version, database vendor, use a second database, communicate with an external system and so on).

Comment: I am developing using nlayers, (not tiers). and I will make all clients connect to SQL server directly by altering the connection string. As you Metioned it will be Thick Client becaue all Logic should be in clients. but I will avoid the mass and latency may cuased to the server due to TCP headache.